# Jquery Toggle Slider & Toggle Text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to slide down a div after the "Show" link is clicked and change that text to "Hide" but it doesn't seem to work so well.

```
<div id="mobilemenu"><a id="#menutoggle" href="#">Show</a></div>
<div id="slider">Content to slide in under #mobilemenu</div>
```

I tried solving with some of the other StackOverflow answers, but I couldn't get it to work so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your anchor. Remove the `#` from the id and attach an event handler.

```
$("#menutoggle").click(function() {
    $("#slider").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small example, of how it might work using what you've provided so far

```
$("#mobilemenu").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#slider").is(":visible")) {
        $("#slider").hide();
        $(this).children("a").text("Show");
    }
    else {
        $("#slider").show();
        $(this).children("a").text("Hide");
    };
});
```

or if you dont have extra work you can simplify it with

```
$("#mobilemenu").click(function(e) { $("#slider").toggle(); });
```

I ddnt use your alink to begin with cause i wanted to show you alink is not necessary and its id'd wrong but if you wanted to use the a link you can use `$("#menutoggle")` in place of `$("#mobilemenu")`